# How to get access token from redirect url

Tags: python, flask, oauth, spotify

I want to get a `access token` from `Spotify`. I get from `Spotify` some this:

> https://example.com/callback#access_token=NwAExz...BV3O2Tk&token_type=Bearer&expires_in=3600&state=123

I see it into address bar. Where `https://example.com/callback` is my site and `access_token` needed value. How to get it?

I tried like this, but get `None`

```
print(flask.request.args.get('access_token'))
```

Full code

```
import flask 
app = flask.Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def render_index():
    return flask.render_template('index.html')

@app.route("/redirect_spotify_token", methods = ['POST'])
def redirect_spotify_token():
    return flask.redirect('https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?...')

@app.route("/callback/spotify_token", methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def callback_token():
  #
  # how to get access token?
  #
  return 'ok'

if __name__ == "__main__":
  app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do my project via a service `repl.it`. Maybe that's why I can't read request's args like this

```
flask.request.args.get('access_token')
```

**Solution**

Redirect from Spotify to `/callback_token`. In this case, function an arg `token` is `None`. The my page `callback_token.html` is parse url and redirect to `callback_token()` with `token`.

**main.py**

```
@app.route("/callback_token")
@app.route("/callback_token/<token>")
def callback_token(token=None):
    if token is None:
      return render_template('callback_token.html')
    else:
      #logic with token
      return redirect(url_for('index'))
```

**callback_token.html** with javascript

```
var parsedHash = new URLSearchParams(
    window.location.hash.substr(1)
);
location.href = `your_url.com/callback_token/${parsedHash.get('access_token')}`
```